# jquery post: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am doing a jquery post send the data to the php file which is in the same domain.

Here is part of code:

```
    var postData = { "score": score };

    $.post("saveScores.php", postData, function() {  //ERROR POINTS THIS LINE
    .....
    });
```

I am getting this error message: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://redirect.main-hosting.com/error404.php/8?domain=quiztest.3eeweb.com. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://quiztest.3eeweb.com' is therefore not allowed access.

**I have hosted this in a subdomain. I have added Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the headers:**

```
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin : http://quiztest.3eeweb.com");
```

But this did not solve the problem.

Is there anything I can do to fix this issue?

Thanks,

Comment: "error404.php" seems like a hint to me, your url is incorrect.

Comment: @Maerlyn the saveScores.php is in the same directory. I tried giving full url: quiztest.3eeweb.com/public/saveScores.php. But even this is not working. I have hosted in a free subdomain. Is this causing the problem?

Comment: Keep in mind that on linux filenames are case-sensitive, that capital "S" may cause a problem that you would not face developing on windows.

Comment: @Maerlyn Thanks. That was the silly mistake. fixed it 's'. just curious to know why redirect url looks like that: "http://redirect.main-hosting.com/error404.php/8?domain=quiztest.3eeweb.com". Because after the above line I am using window.location.href to redirect the page. But redirect is not working.

Comment: That redirect-to-404 is something your hosting does.

Answer (score 0):

I am missing several other headers. You have to add these headers too:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
```

And of course, check that all the http locations are correct.

Addendum:

Remove the http:// part from `Access-Control-Allow-Origin : http://quiztest.3eeweb.com`, like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin : quiztest.3eeweb.com`

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I will test your recommendations now.

Comment: I made the changes but no help. 
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin : quiztest.3eeweb.com");  
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");

Comment: Did you check and double check the location you are posting to? Better get that out of the way first.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your site host is executing some kind of weird redirect.

This is what the ajax request is trying to load:
http://redirect.main-hosting.com/error404.php/8?domain=quiztest.3eeweb.com

I couldn't tell you why they are doing that, but odds are, its not something you can fix. Find better hosting.